# Java implementing Map<String, String> class and use of iterator

Tags: java, interface, iterator

Can anyone please explain me the meaning of implementing Map  class and how should i create an iterator? Iv'e googled this in the past hour and i don't really understand how should implement such interface.

Thanks in advance for any information about it.

Comment: Why do you want to implement the `Map` interface? Is this is homework, please tag it so.

Comment: -1 because it took 10 second to google about it. Just use: JAVA MAP implementation keywords.

Comment: This is not exactly homework, im trying to achieve something for my own use since i heared this is something i should consider in my application

Comment: What ive tried is basiclly understanding this subject via google, i didn't expect any of u to solve a code issue, just to spread more light on this subject..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is a bit hard-to-grasp, but please thoroughly study these:

Implementing a simple Map-Entry

```
public class GenericEntry<KeyType , ValueType> {
    private final KeyType key;
    private ValueType value;

    public MyEntry(KeyType key, ValueType value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public KeyType getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public ValueType getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(ValueType value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Source: [How to implement Map(and other data struct.) in plain Java](http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaDatastructures/article.html#map)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

Answer (score 2):

One site that may be of interest to you - http://www.sergiy.ca/how-to-iterate-over-a-map-in-java/ and example from there at hand:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> entries = map.entrySet().iterator();
while (entries.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry = entries.next();
    System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() + ", Value = " + entry.getValue());
}
```